# check if a list in 2D list is repeated more than one time get the number of repetition

Tags: python

someone to explain how I can  check if a list in 2D list is repeated more than one time and get the number of repetition.

i can get the half of what i'm looking for with:

```
grid[i] in grid # check if there is a line in the 2D list
```

now I want to get the number of repetition

Comment: If `grid[i]` is how you're getting the list to look for, then of course it will appear *at least* once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max(map(grid.count, grid))
```

Demo:

```
grid = [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [1, 2]]

print(max(map(grid.count, grid)))      # prints 2
```

Hmm... after rereading the question, it seems you're actually just asking for `grid.count(grid[i])`. I guess that seemed so trivial that my mind was reading more into the question. Oh well.

Comment: oh men you made my day :) thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid.count(max(grid, key=grid.count)))
```

Or:

```
max(map(grid.count, grid))
```

Comment: Wait... I just realized they never asked for max, how did we both think that? :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Well yeah that's the optimal solution here

Comment: No I mean they're really just asking for `grid.count(grid[i])`, they never asked to find the max number.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Ah yeah! that's true, `max` is slick tho :)

Comment: I will use the grid.count(grid[i]) thank you  @don't talk just code ;)

Comment: @leo Ah, well an upvote on both answers would be really helpful :)